# how to ask to speak with someone who speaks english

Tags: english-to-german

Google translate gives me this:

> Kann ich mit jemandem sprechen, der Englisch spricht?

Is that correct or is there a better way to say it?

Comment: What are your doubts? That's perfectly fine to ask so.

Comment: I had bad experiences with Google translator before, so I wanted to make sure the translation is correct, thanks!

Comment: Google translate has an extensive phrasebook. Standard phrases are usually translated perfectly.

Comment: In order to avoid "bad experiences with Google translator", use http://deepl.com/ . You'll be pleasantly surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly fine. You might also check [asking someone to speak english](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/asking-someone-to-switch-to-english) for one to one conversations.